# Python Discord: Unable to fetch title from embed messages

Tags: python, discord

I have the following message that is being delivered[image]

When I print `print(msg.embeds[0].to_dict())` I do not find *Croagunk* in it at all. All it prints is:

```
{'image': {'url': 'http://161.97.164.151:9000/staticmap/pregenerated/ajhBPJTqvCegguRULe78T79DE4eOnrimPX0J9GuN26s=.png', 'proxy_url': 'https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/MHNRcZFPjiXqpQoNclGQgRi5f-kAl3ppFzj514So5Ts/http/161.97.164.151%3A9000/staticmap/pregenerated/ajhBPJTqvCegguRULe78T79DE4eOnrimPX0J9GuN26s%3D.png', 'width': 640, 'height': 480}, 'thumbnail': {'url': 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nileplumb/PkmnShuffleMap/master/UICONS/pokemon/453.png', 'proxy_url': 'https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/hSu9ru2jL2NOvJtAbvcKNoU-6bGlPGn_UUjoK6nETB0/https/raw.githubusercontent.com/nileplumb/PkmnShuffleMap/master/UICONS/pokemon/453.png', 'width': 128, 'height': 128}, 'color': 16744448, 'type': 'rich', 'description': '<:tm:832296904242233375> 10:30:23 (**20m 47s**) :ballot_box_with_check:\n<:ivs:832296879298445382> 100.00% (**15**/**15**/**15**)\n<:cp:832296750843953192> **517** <:lvl:832296779000184838> **19** \n<:ms:832296731643084821> **Poison Jab** ☠ | **Brick Break**  \n<:capture_1:743526416326328342>34% <:capture_2:743526418574606467> 47% <:capture_3:820574538504732696> 57%\n \n Easterly Road Leeds \nLS8 2TR England \n\n:blue_car: [Google](https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=53.82337752712885,-1.489605919874136) | [Apple](https://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=53.82337752712885,-1.489605919874136) | <:pogomap:667808510255300684> [PoGo-Map](https://pogo-map.com/?lat=53.82337752712885&lon=-1.489605919874136&zoom=18)'}
```

I tried to print `embeds[0].title` but it displays `embeds.Empty`. How do I get it?

Comment: White seeing image, its look like `Croagunk ` isn't inside embed. Its actually in text. Try `print(msg)` to better debug it.

Comment: `Croagunk` would be in `msg.content`